# Passing BIGINT between Erlang VM and the NIFs

Tags: erlang, bigint, erlang-nif

Is there an efficient way to pass BIGINT (integers exceeding 64 bits for x86_64/amd64 architectures) between Erlang VM and the NIFs? So far I haven't found a supporting function in the `enif` module. Maybe converting BIGINTs to binaries will help, but there might be another good way.

Answer (score 4):

[This post from 2011](http://erlang.2086793.n4.nabble.com/Convert-bigint-to-float-in-erl-nif-td4673925.html) says there wasn't any support for big integers in the NIF API at the time. I couldn't find any such function in Erlang/OTP 21's documentation, so the statement is likely true as of today as well.

Here's how you could pass a big integer as an array of bytes:

From Erlang, instead of passing the integer directly, pass two values: the sign of the integer and the binary obtained by calling `binary:encode_unsigned/1` on the integer.

```
Integer = ...,
my_nif_function(Integer < 0, binary:encode_unsigned(Integer)).
```

In the NIF function, you can get access to the bytes of the second argument using [`enif_inspect_binary`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/erl_nif.html#enif_inspect_binary):

```
ErlNifBinary bin;
enif_inspect_binary(env, bin_term, &bin); // make sure to check the return value of this function in the real code
```

`bin.data` now points to `bin.size` bytes, representing the bytes of the integer in Big Endian order (if you want Little Endian, pass `little` as the second argument to `binary:encode_unsigned/2` above).

Comment: Also, a function for converting bytes to the integers (BIGINTs): `crypto:bytes_to_ingeger/1`